# The system cannot find the path specified (Batch file) - Using path with white spaces - PENTAHO spoon.bat (pdi-ce-7.1.0.0-12)

Tags: batch-file, pentaho-spoon

I'm trying to execute a batch file "spoon.bat" from PENTAHO (pdi-ce-7.1.0.0-12), but there is an error.

Part of batch file where the error is found:

```
if "%SPOON_CONSOLE%"=="1" set PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe
if not "%SPOON_CONSOLE%"=="1" set PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe
set IS64BITJAVA=0
call "%~dp0set-pentaho-env.bat"
```

But I receive next below error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

The error is when I'm trying to assign the path where java.exe or javaw.exe are found to "PENTAHO_JAVA".

I've modified the path with double quote mark, but doesn't work; and also I've modified as:

```
if "%SPOON_CONSOLE%"=="1" set "PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\<Program Files (x86)>\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe"
```

Any idea to how declare it to fix it?

Comment: always enclose in quotes variable name and variable content where are spaces `set "pentho_java=C:\programfiles (x86)\...\java.exe"` also `>` and `<` are redirection output and input.

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong, a path is only referenced in the call statement from cmd.exe viewpoint. The other are only variables- The very last command has wrong redirection symbols included.

Comment: Hi elzooilogico. This way doesn't work.

Comment: maybe `set "path=%path%;c:\program files (x86)\...\bin"` before the call

Comment: Sorry, this way also doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Where is the environment variable `PENTAHO_JAVA` referenced?

It must be referenced with `"%PENTAHO_JAVA%"` because the string assigned to this environment variable contains characters like a space or `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``. This is explained in help of Windows command interpreter output on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?` in last paragraph on last help page.

It is of course also possible to define the environment variable with the necessary double quotes already added, i.e. use:

```
if     "%SPOON_CONSOLE%"=="1" set "PENTAHO_JAVA="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe""
if not "%SPOON_CONSOLE%"=="1" set "PENTAHO_JAVA="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe""
set "IS64BITJAVA=0"
call "%~dp0set-pentaho-env.bat"
```

But this is not recommended. Better would be to use

```
if     "%SPOON_CONSOLE%"=="1" set "PENTAHO_JAVA=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe"
if not "%SPOON_CONSOLE%"=="1" set "PENTAHO_JAVA=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe"
set "IS64BITJAVA=0"
call "%~dp0set-pentaho-env.bat"
```

and reference environment variable `PENTAHO_JAVA` enclosed in double quotes where it is necessary to specify its value enclosed in double quotes.

Example:

```
@echo off
rem Get path of latest installed Java directly from Windows registry.
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2*" %%N in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\javaws.exe" /v Path 2^>nul') do if /I "%%N" == "Path" set "PENTAHO_JAVA=%%P" & goto JavaPathFound

rem Path of Java not found in registry, search for 32-bit Java in the default
rem program files folders of 64-bit and 32-bit Windows and take first found.
if "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" goto Windows_x86
for /R "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" %%I in (java*.exe) do set "PENTAHO_JAVA=%%~dpI" & goto JavaPathFound
:Windows_x86
for /R "%ProgramFiles%" %%I in (java*.exe) do set "PENTAHO_JAVA=%%~dpI" & goto JavaPathFound

echo Error: Java binary directory not found.
echo/
pause
goto :EOF

:ErrorJavaEXE
echo Error: File %PENTAHO_JAVA% not found.
echo/
pause
goto :EOF

:JavaPathFound
if not "%PENTAHO_JAVA:~-1%" == "\" set "PENTAHO_JAVA=%PENTAHO_JAVA%\"
if "%SPOON_CONSOLE%" == "1" (
    set "PENTAHO_JAVA=%PENTAHO_JAVA%java.exe"
) else (
    set "PENTAHO_JAVA=%PENTAHO_JAVA%javaw.exe"
)

rem Check existence of Java executable to run.
if not exist "%PENTAHO_JAVA%" goto ErrorJavaEXE

"%PENTAHO_JAVA%" -version
call "%~dp0set-pentaho-env.bat"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `rem /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` whereby redirection operator must be escaped in this batch code on **FOR** command line with caret character `^`. And read answer on [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343351/) for an explanation of `&` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, don't modify the shell scripts coming with Kettle.  You're supposed to set certain environment variables to adapt the scripts to your runtime environment.  Look at the top comment section in script `set-pentaho-env` to learn what's best for your system.

BTW: The current Java 8 security baseline 8u131 was released in April 2017 - you're way behind that.  Also, are you aware of the fact that you are using a 32bit JVM with limited RAM support?